# .Net Dictionary and the Overriding of Equals

Tags: .net, dictionary

I know that when I create a dictionary with a custom class as key, the match when I provide a key is done through reference compare. For example:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public object SomeValue { get; set; }
}

// ....
public static void Main()
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<SomeClass, string>();

    var key1 = new SomeClass { SomeValue = 30 };
    dict[key1] = "30";

    Console.WriteLine(dict[key1]); // prints "30"

    var key2 = new SomeClass { SomeValue = 30 };
    Console.WriteLine(dict[key2]); // prints null 
}
```

What happens if I override Equals (and ==) in the `SomeClass` class? Will I get "30" on the second line of the output?

And what if I want to have a dictionary that is based on references instead of member values, but I have overridden Equals?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Short Answer

Yes if you override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods your custom key comparison will start working.

### Long Answer

The `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` class does not necessarily do a reference based comparison.  It instead uses the `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` instance which can be provided to the constructor.  If not provided the default is `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`.

The processes by which `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` works is complicated.  But a summary is

- Looks for `IEquatable<T>` on the type and if present it is used for equality
- Defaults to using the `Equals` method which by default is `Object.Equals` and hence a reference comparison

So types can override the the comparison at a couple of levels

- By specifying a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>`
- Implementing `IEquatable<T>` and overriding `GetHashCode`
- Overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode`

The equality operators `==` and `!=` do not come into play for the `TKey` type in a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`.

Comment: Your long answer should maybe reiterate the bit about GetHashCode. None of what you described will happen if the hash codes don't match.

Comment: @Joe added the `GetHashCode` portion to the `IEquatable<T>` discussion.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Would best practice require that any derived class whose base type implements iEquatable of its (the base's) own type override that, in addition to implementing iEquatable of its (the derived class)'s own type?  That would seem to be a fair bit of extra work, with substantial possibilities for malfunction if a type is missed (since the base's iEquatable implemention might get called instead of the derived one).

Comment: @supercat: Equality in type hierarchies is fundamentally messy. Obeying the equals contract requires checking that the other object is of *exactly* your type, as otherwise it's hard to work reflexively. For non-sealed classes, I prefer using an explicit IEqualityComparer - that way you can compare any way you want.

Comment: Quick question: do I have to write a IEqualityComparer to do a reference base comparison or is there one out-of-the-box?

Comment: @Bruno Brant: An iEqualityComparer can simply call its own Equals method.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I can see some real benefit for a sealed class implementing iEquatable<ItsOwnType>.  It would allow collections of that type to compare objects without the typecasting, type comparisons, or (for structs) boxing operations that would be needed with Object.Equals.  If a type is inheritable, however, a proper iEquatable implementation would have to check the type of the target object and typecast to its own type, so I'm not sure what benefit one would gain from iEquatable.

Comment: @supercat: Exactly. Not only does it not bring benefit - it brings confusion. If you can point to a *specific* equality comparison which is performed, that's a lot nicer than guessing what exactly the equatable implementation will do.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: So would it be fair to suggest that implementing iEquatable<T> is a big benefit when T is a struct, a small benefit when it is a sealed class, a potentially-useful behavior when T is an interface, and a bad idea if T is an inheritable class?  For the interface scenario, I think it might also be useful to have iEquatable2<T> which would inherit iEquatable<T> and would implement an Equal2 method.  The Equals2 method would return true or false if it knew enough about the other object to determine truth or falsity, and would otherwise return the other object's Equals.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: This would allow, for example, an "immutable picture" interface where pictures could either be stored as some type of bitmap or information necessary to construct one.  Two iPicture objects could be compared by converting each to a bitmap, a picture object might know how to compare itself to some specific types of iPicture without having to do such conversion.

Comment: @supercat: I wouldn't do it for interfaces at all, to be honest. I think using a separate `IEqualityComparer<T>` makes much more sense in that case.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: If an interface defines an immutable view of an object, and if it is expected that such views will be used as keys, then having the interface "inherit" iEquatable(of Itself) might seem sensible.  Are we in agreement that iEquatable(of anInheritableType) is generally bad, though?

Comment: @supercat: Yes, we're in agreement on the latter point. But I view any interface as implicitly "an inheritable type" which is why I disagree on the former bit :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: You're probably right.  Interfaces have behavior that's a bit different from inheritance and wouldn't be problematic, but an inheritable class might implement an interface (in which case it would be better if the class didn't have to implement iEquatable).